# JS - map over an object to extract info and create a new object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to iterate over an existing object, extract some values and assign the extracted values to a new object.

The article.author.id and article.author.name are taken from the articles object. the 'active' key is new and will default to true for all.

```
const extractAuthors = (articles) => {
        let authorObj = {}
        articles.map(article => {
            console.log(article.author.id); 
            console.log(article.author.name);
            authorObj = {...authorObj, {'id': article.author.id, 'name': article.author.name, 'active': true}} 
        })
        return authorObj;
    };
```

As an author might write multiple articles, only unique author.ids should be added to end up with a unique list of authors in the object.

I've achieved what I needed with Map but Map only stores key=>value pairs, so I had nowhere to attach the 'active' key.

```
const extractAuthors = (articles) => {
        let authorMap = new Map();
        articles.map(article => {
            if(!authorMap.has(article.author.id)) {
                authorMap.set(article.author.id, article.author.name)
            }
        })
        return authorMap;
    };
```

Edited: Following the comments, that's a Map version that works:

```
const extractAuthors = (articles) => {
        let authorMap = new Map();
        articles.forEach(article => {
            if(!authorMap.has(article.author.id)) {
                authorMap.set(article.author.id, {name: article.author.name, active: 'true'})
            }
        })
        return authorMap;
    };
```

Out of curiosity, how would it be done correctly as an object?

Comment: Instead of adding article.author.name in the value of Map, you can set the object like 
authorMap.set(article.author.id, {name:article.author.name,active:'true'})

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` than you shouldn't be using `.map()`. Use `.forEach()` instead or return something that you can pass to the `Map()` constructor.

Comment: Thank you. It works as a map now. Out of curiosity, how would I achieve it as an object (what I was trying to do in the first snippet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has syntax error. I took the liberty of editing a few things.
This should help:

```js
const extractAuthors = (articles) => {
  const authorObj = {}; // for maintaining uniqueness
  const authors = []; // aggregating unique authors

  for (const article of articles) {
    const id = article.author.id;
    if (!authorObj[id]) {
      authorObj[id] = true;
      authors.push({ ...article.author, active: true });
    }
  }
  console.log("Authors aggragated: ", authors);
};

const articles = [
  { author: { id: "id1", name: "name1" } },
  { author: { id: "id2", name: "name2" } },
  { author: { id: "id1", name: "name3" } },
];

extractAuthors(articles);
```